# Start another activity in background on start of main activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 2 activities Activity A and Activity B.

Activity B start on click of button in Activity A.

I want to start Activity B in background when the Activity A is created and move to Activity B when I click on button in Activity A.

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: What is main reason behind this ....

Comment: Fetching some data from the cloud which slows the activity b hence i think lets start in background meanwhile activity a is loaded so that data is fetched

Answer (score 0):

If you want something that runs in background , then you go for service not the activity

Comment: Need UI also hence i go for activity

Comment: use  moveTaskToBack (true);

Comment: I think this cmd runs the activity in background even if we press back button.